# Is there any way of changing individual elements in a 2D array, with multiple iterations of a for loop in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop

i.e. for the second iteration of a loop, I want to change a specific element to something else....

I am still new to C++ and Stack Overflow your help us greatly appreciated

```
std:: string ecoClass[5][14]
        {
            {"|A1", "|A2|", "A3|", "----", "|A4", "|A5", "|A6|"},
            {"|F1", "|F2|", "F3|", "----", "|F4", "|F5", "|F6|"},
            {"|G1", "|G2|", "G3|", "----", "|G4", "|G5", "|G6|"},
            {"|H1", "|H2|", "H3|", "----", "|H4", "|H5", "|H6|"},
            {"|I1", "|I2|",}
        };
```

let me try to clarify a bit. If I put this array in a for loop. I want to change elements based on what number my for loop counter is on

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)…based on that for loop is there any way to change elements in my code, e.g. if i=2, I would like ecoClass[0][0]="|**";

and when i=3;

ecoClass[1][2]="|**"

Comment: How does the for loop look like? What is the problem with this for loop?

Comment: `ecoClass[2][3] = "foo"`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you want to change the first element of your array, then maybe a ternary operator would be enough? If you want our answers to be accurate, please try to post a more precise question with enough of your code for us to understand

Comment: it isnt obvious what problem you encoutered while writing the loop and changing `ecoClass[0][0]` in its second iteration. Please post a [mcve] of your code so we can more easily help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: basically to clarify slightly I want to change elements of my array, based on the for loop, i.e if the for loop counter is on 2, then i want to change an element in the array...hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: *" e.g. if i=2, I would like ecoClass[0][0]=..."*, So, why not `if ( i == 2 ) { ecoClass[0][0] = ...}`? I'm wondering what is the actual problem you are trying to solve implementing this loop.

Comment: @Bob__, That is what I did in the end, I'm trying to write a program that books seats for a bus, multiple times and I wanted a way to check if the seat is available, for example, if someone chooses seat "A1" I need a way for my program to make sure it cant be chosen twice, any recommendations?